# SharePoint Online theme not visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

I created a new theme using the Theme Generator and uploaded it to our tenant via PowerShell. I can also check it with `Get-SPOTheme`. I cannot, however apply this to an existing site collection, I don't even see it under "change look".

I tried with 2 brand new site collections (team site - classic and also a publishing portal), none of them worked.

How can I make the new theme available? I watched tutorial videos and, according to them, this is the way it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the modern site?

Adding a theme ([Add-SPOTheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-powershell)) does not apply the theme to any sites. It adds the theme to your tenant store, and then the theme will be available in the list of themes under the Change the look option for **modern pages**.

[Create a **modern team site**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40067.sharepoint-online-modern-team-sites.aspx) and then click "change the look" from the gear on the top of the **modern page**.
 [image]

If you are using the **classic site**, navigate to Site settings > **Composed looks**, check you have deployed it.

Learn more about [deploying a custom theme in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and stumbled upon this post.

For anyone who still has the problem: Make sure you connect to the right session and use the `connect-sposervice` and not `connect-pnponline`.

In my case this was the problem.